# Rails: Subclass not registering as instance of parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Rails app I am working in, I have code like the following:

```
# app/models/a.rb
class A < ActiveRecord::Base; ...; end
# app/models/b.rb
class B < A; ...; end

# /app/elsewhere...

do_case(B.new)

def do_case(letter)
  case letter
  when A
    "not nil"
  end
end
```

When I run this locally it performs as expected and I get "not nil" as the return value. But I get `nil` in my test environment.

The test environment shows that `A` is among the ancestors (`B.ancestors`) of `letter` (`B.new`), but fails to register as a subclass with the case equality operator or `is_a?(A)`.

```
A === B.new #=> false in test environment, true locally
B.new.is_a?(A)  #=> false in test environment, true locally
```

This seems like a Rails autoloading issue, but I'm not sure why these methods would be failing if the parent class is included in the ancestors in both environments. What's going on?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce.

Comment: @Ilya I'm pretty sure it's an autloading issue caused by all the many other classes in the application. Too big to reproduce here, too private to link to the repo.

Comment: This is quite likely an issue with `spring`. Are you using `spring`? If so, try killing `spring` first, then try your test again. As you said, the `case/when` should be using the `is_a?` calls and `B.new.is_a?(A)` will return `true`

Answer (score 0):

Agree, this looks like an autoloading issue. While not ideal, you can resolve it by adding a `require_dependency` call in `B`.

As far as where to look for the root issue, it's possible that you have some library dependencies in your test environment that don't exist on Test. I would load a REPL on Test and inspect `A`. Some useful methods:

```
class A
  def self.what_is_my_nesting
    Module.nesting
  end
end

A.what_is_my_nesting
A.ancestors
B.ancestors
```

etc